# @ResponseBody is not returning String message to error, throwing 404 WhiteLabel error page

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am following a tutorial on Spring MVC and my project is not working as expected. I am using @ResponseBody to return a string message but it is throwing a whitelabel error page. I have scoured the Internet for last 2 days but still clueless about what could I possibly do wrong. Can anybody throw some light upon this?
Spring Framework boot : 2.5.4, Java version : 11

Code snippet for LoginController :

```
package com.in28minutes.springboot.web.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class LoginController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces="text/plain")
    @ResponseBody
    public String loginMessage() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

> 2021-09-10 15:33:54.158 DEBUG 8556 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/login", parameters={}
> 2021-09-10 15:33:54.158 DEBUG 8556 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [Classpath [META-INF/resources/], Classpath [resources/], Classpath [static/], Classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
> 2021-09-10 15:33:54.160 DEBUG 8556 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
> 2021-09-10 15:33:54.160 DEBUG 8556 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
> 2021-09-10 15:33:54.160 DEBUG 8556 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
> 2021-09-10 15:33:54.161 DEBUG 8556 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
> 2021-09-10 15:33:54.177 DEBUG 8556 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, text/html;q=0.8]
> 2021-09-10 15:33:54.178 DEBUG 8556 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootFirstWebApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootFirstWebApplication.class, 
args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Which URL did you test?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/login

Comment: Do you have different context path in your `application.yml`? `server.servlet.contextPath: /<yourAppName>` the your URL would be `localhost:8080/<yourAppName>/login`

Comment: This code works for me using Spring 2.5.4 and Java 13. Can you post your application.properties and application.yml as well?

Edit: Also do you have any special Configs with your application?

Answer (score 1):

The response provided by @joaompdias should work well, however if you are not willing to have the class `SpringBootFirstWebApplication` and controller classes in the same package tree you can use the annotation attribute `scanBasePackages` to define the packages where spring boot should look for controller classes as shown below

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.in28minutes.springboot.web.controller")
public class SpringBootFirstWebApplication {
...
}
```

Refer to [api documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.4/api/) for further details

Answer (score 0):

I will guess that your `SpringBootFirstWebApplication` is not placed in the parent package of all other packages in your application and therefore `@Controller` annotation in `LoginController` is not scanned.

If that is the case, change `SpringBootFirstWebApplication` to the parent package of all other packages in your application.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like your requested URL in  @RequestMapping is wrong. Your expected URL is **value="/home"**, but your actual is **value="/login"**

Comment: sorry, that was a typo...I am still getting the same error even though I post the correct url...the error message is updated in the original post...

Comment: try to change annotation Controller to RestController